# Use python to calculate summation of current row, left 3 row and right 3 row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Per screenshot example [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6hnB.png) , given [Gross Forecast] and [SO], I want to calculate [Net] based on logic: SO first deduct value in current week (W0) then it goes back 3 weeks then it goes forward 3 weeks, this calculation stops when a positive value is reached.

I added the example data to a python data frame:

```
            import pandas as pd
            import numpy as np

            data = {
                "Material": ["ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC"],
                "Week": [
                    "2019-W50",
                    "2019-W49",
                    "2019-W48",
                    "2019-W47",
                    "2019-W51",
                    "2019-W52",
                    "2020-W1",
                ],
                "Gross Forecast": [50, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50],
                "SO Qty": [-200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            }

            df = pd.DataFrame(data)
            print(df)
```

wanted result is a data frame like:

```
                data = {
                "Material": ["ABC"],
                "Week": ["2019-W51"],
                "Net": [20]
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data).sort_values(by=['Week'])
df['diff'] = df['Gross Forecast'] + df['SO Qty']
df['calc_steps1'] = df['diff'] + df['diff'].shift(1)
df['calc_steps2'] = df['calc_steps1'] + df['diff'].shift(2)
df['calc_steps3'] = df['calc_steps2'] + df['diff'].shift(3)
df['net'] = df['Gross Forecast'] + df['calc_steps3'].shift(1)
```

Comment: Thanks. But how to let Python dynamically calculate the steps where it stops when a positive value is reached? The example I gave has 4 steps but it is not always 4 steps when there are new set of values.